# Can mvvmFX objects (View, ViewModel, Model) be created using CDI?

Tags: java, javafx, mvvmfx

I think about using mvvmFX framework for JavaFX but I don't understand if it supports CDI. In [wiki](https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX/wiki) page about CDI is not ready. Could anyone say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mvvmFX supports CDI. There is a [separate module](https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX/tree/develop/mvvmfx-cdi) for CDI that you should include in your project.
Some basic informations about using dependency injection in general with mvvmFX and with CDI can be found in the wiki [here](https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX/wiki/Dependency-Injection).

There is also an [example application](https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX/tree/develop/examples/contacts-example) using CDI available in the repository.